# Show that the following set is open: $S = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x^3 + x > 1 \}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In my real analysis first exam, I had the following problem:

Show that this set is open

$$S = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x^3 + x > 1 \}$$

At that point we did not cover continuity, functions or sequences yet, I mean when I took the exam, I only knew the properties of real numbers, inequalities, absolute values, boundedness of a set, Archimedean property, mathematical induction, the definition of an open set, and more, but I think that goes beyond this question. I know it can be solved with continuity, but the instructor did not talk about it in class so there must be another way

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Okay for one, do not use ChatGPT on your math homework. That is lazy, unhelpful, and non-mathematical. ChatGPT is not built to do math.

Comment: Do you know anything about continuous functions and their relation to open sets?

Comment: It's not so weird to use tools of analysis to work on examples in basic topology. After all, topology is an abstraction of analysis.

Comment: If you want to be taken seriously in this forum, avoid to mention ChatGPT, it knows nothing about Mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much topology you know, I can give two ways to show this. Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto x^3+x$. We know that $f$ is continuous, so by the topological definition of continuity, the preimage $S=f^{-1}((1,\infty))$ is also open, because $(1,\infty)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Alternatively, you can show that $S$ is open by picking an arbitrary $a\in S$ an showing that there exists $\delta>0$ such that $(a-\delta,a+\delta)\subseteq S$. Since $f(a)>1$, we can find $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f(a)-\varepsilon>1$ still. Use continuity of $f$ to find a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(a)-f(b)|<\varepsilon$ for all $b\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)$. Then for such a $b$, we necessarily have $f(b)>1$, which shows that $(a-\delta,a+\delta)\subseteq S$. Therefore $S$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.